# Access a managed property in filter

Tags: jsf-2, properties, servlet-filters

In my attempts to find out the reason for the problems stated in this question: [JSF2 slow page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532524/jsf2-slow-page-loading), I would like to time a user session filter I use. I've created a timer that is an ApplicationScoped bean.

My question is if it's possible to access this bean as a managed property from the filter. In my other beans I can do this, although in the filter the managed property is always null.

Comment: When you said "filter", do you actually mean `javax.servlet.Filter`? (if so, you should have used `[servlet-filters]` tag, not `[filter]`!) The currently accepted answer makes in this case then no sense.

Comment: You're right. I've changed the tag to the correct one. Regarding the answer, the last suggestion worked. I'm still not sure how the mechanism of ManagedProperty works in this context though.

Comment: The `FacesContext` is normally not available in a servlet filter at all, so why it works for you is beyond me. The managed property works in a managed bean only, however a servlet filter is not a managed bean. Your question is then basically answered by the very same answer as on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633112/jsf-get-managed-bean-by-name

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me and the examples in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Access your **application scoped** bean from filter in the follwoing way

```
ServletContext context = req.getServletContext();
MyAppBean myAppBean = (MyAppBean) context.getAttribute("myAppBean");
```

Access your **session scoped** bean from filter in the following way

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getSession(false);
MyAppBean myAppBean = (MyAppBean ) session.getAttribute("myAppBean");
```

---

**Original Answer :**

Yes you can , make it `(eager = true)` , and add the needed annotations

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyAppBean { }
```

and in your sesion scoped bean access it like this

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{myAppBean }")
private MyAppBean myAppBean; //add getter and setter
```

If your bean is not a `@ManagedBean` you can access it from the `ApplicationMap` like this

```
MyAppBean myAppBean = (MyAppBean ) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
    getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("country");
```

If the bean you want to access is a `@SessionScoped` you can grab it from the `SessionMap` like this

```
MyAppBean myAppBean = (MyAppBean ) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
    getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("country");
```

---

Here you got some nice tutorial on how to access beans from a non managed beans

[Access A Managed Bean From Event Listener – JSF](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/access-a-managed-bean-from-event-listener-jsf/)

Comment: It made no difference, I'm afraid. Does the filter need to be a bean for this to work? Currently it's not.

Comment: It worked using your last solution. Registering the filter as a ManagedBean did not though. Weird. Thanks for your help!